Solving system of linear equations with AutoDiffXd type
I have an equation in the form of M(q, dq)*ddq + C(q, dq) + G(q) = f, where I need to solve for ddq. I am running into an error where np.linalg.solve (and the scipy variant) is not compatible with Drake's AutoDiffXd type. How can I resolve this?
from pydrake.systems.framework import LeafSystem_, Context, VectorBase, ContinuousState
from pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion import TemplateSystem

import numpy as np

from BallbotMPC.ballbot_params import BallbotParams



@TemplateSystem.define("BallbotSystem_")
def BallbotSystem_(T):
    class Impl(LeafSystem_[T]):
        def _construct(self, converter=None, params=BallbotParams()):
            LeafSystem_[T].__init__(self, converter=converter)

            self._params = params

            self.DeclareContinuousState(4) # q: 4 states [ball angle, ball velocity, lean angle, lean velocity]

            self._command_port = self.DeclareVectorInputPort("u", 4)

            self._state_port = self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("state", 4, self.CopyStateOut)


        def _construct_copy(self, other, converter=None):
            Impl._construct(self, converter=converter, params=other._params)


        def DoCalcTimeDerivatives(self, context: Context, derivatives: ContinuousState):
            # constants
            mass = self._params.mass_k + self._params.mass_a + self._params.mass_w
            radius_total = self._params.radius_k + self._params.radius_w
            gam = self._params.l * self._params.mass_a + radius_total * self._params.mass_w

            state = self._state_port.Eval(context)
            u = self._command_port.Eval(context)

            # Dtype, necessary for numpy to understand the type of the drake types (AutoDiffXd, etc.)
            dtype = type(state[0])
            print(dtype)

            # Mass term in Langrangian formulation (Eqn. 2.22)
            M_x = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=dtype)
            M_x[0, 0] = mass * self._params.radius_k ** 2 + self._params.Theta_k + (self._params.radius_k / self._params.radius_w) ** 2 * self._params.Theta_w
            M_x[0, 1] = -(self._params.radius_k / self._params.radius_w ** 2) * radius_total * self._params.Theta_w + gam * self._params.radius_k * np.cos(state[2])
            M_x[1, 0] = M_x[0, 1]
            M_x[1, 1] = (radius_total / self._params.radius_w) ** 2 * self._params.Theta_w + self._params.Theta_a + self._params.mass_a * self._params.l ** 2 + self._params.mass_w * radius_total ** 2

            # Coriolis term in Langrangian formulation (Eqn. 2.23)
            C_x = np.zeros(2, dtype=dtype)
            C_x[0] = -self._params.radius_k * gam * np.sin(state[2]) * state[3] ** 2

            # Gravitational term in Lagrangian formulation (Eqn. 2.24)
            G_x = np.zeros(2, dtype=dtype)
            G_x[1] = -self._params.g * np.sin(state[2]) * gam

            # Non-potential force term in Lagrangian formulation (Eqn. 2.17 + Eqn. 2.18)
            f_np = np.zeros(2, dtype=dtype)
            f_np[0] = self._params.radius_k / self._params.radius_w * u
            f_np[1] = -f_np[0]

            # Solve for ddq in M(q, dq)*ddq + C(q, dq) + G(q) = f_np
            ddq = np.linalg.solve(M_x, f_np - C_x - G_x)


            derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(0, state[1])
            derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(1, ddq[0])
            derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(2, state[3])
            derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetAtIndex(3, ddq[1])


        def CopyStateOut(self, context: Context, output: VectorBase):
            state = context.get_continuous_state_vector().CopyToVector()
            output.SetFromVector(state)
            

    return Impl


BallbotSystem = BallbotSystem_[None]

Using Ubuntu 24.04, with Drake 1.34.0 and numpy 2.1.3 in a python 3.12 virtual environment.

At the moment, solving the linear system x = A\b with A, b being array of AutoDiffScalar is only supported in Drake C++, not in pydrake.
To get around it, you could convert A and b to JAX array, and call A\b in JAX, and convert the result back to numpy array of AutoDiffScalar.
